# Python Pandas: Convert Minutes to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, time

**The Data:**

I have a column of data with time in minutes.

```
data_df = [2000, 4000, 392, 600]
```

**The Question:**

How can I convert it into a week, day, hour and minute into a datetime format that pandas can deal with?

**Example:**

Assuming time = 0 corresponds to '01-Jan-2010 00:00', how to I convert 2000 minutes to 02-Jan-2010 09:20'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Construct a `TimedeltaIndex` from that column and add to your initial date:

```
In [6]:
df['time'] = dt.datetime(2010,1,1) + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['minutes'], unit='m')
df

Out[6]:
   minutes                time
0     2000 2010-01-02 09:20:00
1     4000 2010-01-03 18:40:00
2      392 2010-01-01 06:32:00
3      600 2010-01-01 10:00:00
```